# Python convert a dict object including list to list including dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping

I guess the title may make you a little bit confused but i'm sure that too many people facing with this issue and most of them probably know how to solve it.

Here is my issue, i have a dict object like below:

```
{   'fields':
    ['Config', 'Device', 'Device Name', 'Config Name', 'description', 'ip', 'radius', 'ssid','vlan', 'channel', 'frequency', 'maxclients', 'username', 'password', 'enable_password','transport_protocol', 'personality', 'date_added', 'date_modified'],
    'results': [
    [23, 45, 'New test2 for demo', 'New test2 for demo', 'Default desc for device','192.168.0.100',13, '0', 0, 4, 'None', None, 'Cisco', 'Cisco', 'Cisco', 'Telnet', 'ios',datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 6, 13, 52, 14), datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 7, 14, 27, 39)],
    [23, 47, 'Test after a couple hours', 'New test2 for demo', 'Default desc for device','192.168.0.100', 13, '0', 0, 4, 'None', None, 'Cisco', 'Cisco', 'Cisco', 'Telnet', 'ios',datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 6, 13, 52, 14), datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 7, 14, 27, 39)]
    ]
}
```

I would like to convert it into a list includes dict object like this:

```
[
{'username': 'Cisco', 'transport_protocol': 'Telnet', 'Device Name': 'With a fresh breath','description': 'Default desc for device', 'date_added': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 8, 9, 32, 13),'date_modified': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 8, 9, 32, 13), 'ip': '192.168.0.100', 'vlan': 0,'enable_password': 'Cisco', 'Config Name': 'With a fresh breath', 'frequency': '0', 'radius': 0, 'personality': 'ios', 'Device': 49, 'maxclients': 0, 'password': 'Cisco', 'Config': 27, 'channel': 0, 'ssid': 'LBREAP'}, 
{'username': 'Cisco', 'transport_protocol': 'Telnet', 'Device Name': 'With a fresh breath for second device', 'description': 'Default desc for device', 'date_added': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 8, 9, 33, 57), 'date_modified': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 8, 11, 23, 1), 'ip': '192.168.0.35', 'vlan': 0, 'enable_password': 'Cisco', 'Config Name': 'With a fresh breath for second device', 'frequency': '0', 'radius': 0, 'personality': 'ios', 'Device': 50, 'maxclients': 0, 'password': 'Cisco', 'Config': 28, 'channel': 4, 'ssid': 'LBREAP'}
]
```

I need to map top object fields turn into second object keys with a list. I've written a simple for to make second one and it works, i created second one already with this for, but i'm curious about that there is an easy way to make that work.

Here is my loop:

```
results = list()
if configSet['results']:
   k = 0
   for i in configSet['results']:
       rSet = {}
       r = 0
       for f in i:
           rSet[configSet['fields'][r]] = f
           r += 1
       results.insert(k, rSet)
       k += 1
```

I try to handle with dict, list, map and zip combination like this

```
dict(map(list, zip(configSet['fields'], configSet['results'])))
```

but it did not work for me.

Is there any one suggest to me a better, fast and easy way to do that?

Regards.

Comment: Suggested title: converting separate label and value lists into a list of dicts in python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[dict(zip(configSet['fields'], result)) for result in configSet['results']]
```

For each result in `results`, make a dict with keys from `fields` and values from the result.

```
In [6]: [dict(zip(configSet['fields'], result)) for result in configSet['results']]
Out[6]:
[{'Config': 23,
  'Config Name': 'New test2 for demo',
  'Device': 45,
  'Device Name': 'New test2 for demo',
  'channel': 4,
  'date_added': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 6, 13, 52, 14),
  'date_modified': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 7, 14, 27, 39),
  'description': 'Default desc for device',
  'enable_password': 'Cisco',
  'frequency': 'None',
  'ip': '192.168.0.100',
  'maxclients': None,
  'password': 'Cisco',
  'personality': 'ios',
  'radius': 13,
  'ssid': '0',
  'transport_protocol': 'Telnet',
  'username': 'Cisco',
  'vlan': 0},
 {'Config': 23,
  'Config Name': 'New test2 for demo',
  'Device': 47,
  'Device Name': 'Test after a couple hours',
  'channel': 4,
  'date_added': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 6, 13, 52, 14),
  'date_modified': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 7, 14, 27, 39),
  'description': 'Default desc for device',
  'enable_password': 'Cisco',
  'frequency': 'None',
  'ip': '192.168.0.100',
  'maxclients': None,
  'password': 'Cisco',
  'personality': 'ios',
  'radius': 13,
  'ssid': '0',
  'transport_protocol': 'Telnet',
  'username': 'Cisco',
  'vlan': 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where you get the 'fresh breathes', but I think this does what you want to do:

```
d={'fields':['Config',...],'results': [[23,...],[23,...]]}
keys=['username', 'transport_protocol', 'Device Name', ...]
resultlist = [{field:value for field,value in zip(keys, [v[d['fields'].index(k)] for k in keys])} for v in d['results']]
```

**Edit:** Just saw the primary answer, which uses the variant `dict(keys, values)` rather than my confusing `{key:value for key,value in ...}`, so mine is at most redundant. What hopefully makes my answer nonetheless somehow relevant is that it allows for selecting keys from a subset, which I originally thought was your goal.

Output:

```
[
  {'username': 'Cisco', 'transport_protocol': 'Telnet', 'Device Name': 'New test2 for demo'}, 
  {'username': 'Cisco', 'transport_protocol': 'Telnet', 'Device Name': 'Test after a couple hours'}
]
```